# Bootstrap 4 ajax success message quickly flashes by

Tags: jquery, ajax, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm using Bootstrap 4 and have a form modal. Upon submission of the form, my success message shows up for a split second and then disappears. The data successfully inserts into my database and the popup alert box successfully shows. I could use that and not worry about the message in the DIV but I'd like to learn how to do that properly. Below is my code along with a few things I've tried commented out:

#### Javascript

```
    <script>
            $("button#submit").click(function() {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "insert.php",
                    data: $('form.feedback').serialize(),

                   success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
    $("#feedback").html(data);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#feedback").addClass('hide');
        $('.close').trigger('click');// NOTICE THIS CHANGE HERE.
    }, 5000);
},

                    error: function() {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
                return false; 
            });
    </script>
```

Here is my DIV to display the message:

```
<div id="feedback">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data- 
     target="#feedback-modal">Setup Your Course</button>
</div>
```

#### Modal HTML

```
<div id="feedback-modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
                <h3>Setup Your Course</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="feedback" name="feedback">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <label>Department</label>
                            <input type="text" name="Department" id="Department" class="form-control" />
                            <br/>
                            <label>Course Number</label>
                            <input type="text" name="CourseNumber" id="CourseNumber" class="form-control" />
                            <br/>
                            <label>Course Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="CourseName" id="CourseName" class="form-control" />
                            <br/>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">

                            <label>Section Number</label>
                            <input type="text" name="SectionNumber" id="SectionNumber" class="form-control" />
                            <br/>

                            <label>Faculty</label>
                            <input type="text" name="Faculty" id="Faculty" class="form-control" />
                            <br/>
                            <label>Semester</label>
                            <input type="text" name="Semester" id="Semester" class="form-control" />
                            <br/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">

                            <label>Year</label>
                            <input type="text" name="Year" id="Year" class="form-control" />
                            <br/>
                            <label>Semester Start</label>
                            <input type="text" name="Startsemester" id="Startsemester" class="form-control" />
                            <br/>
                            <label>Semester End</label>
                            <input type="text" name="Endsemester" id="Startsemester" class="form-control" />
                            <br/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" />
                <input type="hidden" name="operation" id="operation" />

                <!--<input type="submit" name="action" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add"/> -->
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Send</button>


                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
```

Complete HTML Code:

```
<?php
//if a session does not yet exist for this user, start one
session_start();
include_once( '../admin/body.php' );
include_once( '../config.php' );
include_once( '../functions.php' );


BodyHeader( "Course Setup", '', '' );
?>
<link href="../adminpanel/css/helper.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../adminpanel/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:** -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https:**oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https:**oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style type="text/css">
    .modal-lg {
        max-width: 80% !important;
    }
</style>
<!-- Container fluid  -->
<div id="feedback"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#feedback-modal">Setup Your Course</button>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Course Setup</h1>

    <!-- Start Page Content -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class=".col-xl-
">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h3 class="card-subtitle">Input the basic information for your course(s).</h3>
                    <div align="right">
                        <button type="button" id="add_button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#feedback-modal" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Add</button>
                    </div>


                    <div class="table-responsive m-t-40">
                        <table id="example23" class="display nowrap table table-hover table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Dept</th>
                                    <th>Course #</th>
                                    <th>Course Name</th>
                                    <th>Section #</th>
                                    <th>Faculty</th>
                                    <th>Semester</th>
                                    <th>Year</th>
                                    <th>Semester Start</th>
                                    <th>Semester End</th>


                                    <th>Edit</th>
                                    <th>Delete</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Dept</th>
                                    <th>Course #</th>
                                    <th>Course Name</th>
                                    <th>Section #</th>
                                    <th>Faculty</th>
                                    <th>Semester</th>
                                    <th>Year</th>
                                    <th>Semester Start</th>
                                    <th>Semester End</th>


                                    <th>Edit</th>
                                    <th>Delete</th>
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                            <tbody>

                                <?php
                                $stmt = $connection->prepare( "
    SELECT CourseID, Department, CourseNumber, CourseName, SectionNumber, Faculty, Semester, Year, Startsemester, Endsemester FROM Courses
" );

                                $stmt->execute();
                                $result = $stmt->get_result();
                                //if ($result->num_rows === 0) exit('No rows');

                                while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
                                    $CourseID = $row[ 'CourseID' ];
                                    $Department = $row[ 'Department' ];
                                    $CourseNumber = $row[ 'CourseNumber' ];
                                    $CourseName = $row[ 'CourseName' ];
                                    $SectionNumber = $row[ 'SectionNumber' ];
                                    $Faculty = $row[ 'Faculty' ];
                                    $Semester = $row[ 'Semester' ];
                                    $Year = $row[ 'Year' ];
                                    $Startsemester = $row[ 'Startsemester' ];
                                    $Endsemester = $row[ 'Endsemester' ];

                                    ?>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <?php echo "$Department"; ?>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <?php echo "$CourseNumber"; ?>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <?php echo "$CourseName"; ?>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <?php echo "$SectionNumber"; ?>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <?php echo "$Faculty"; ?>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <?php echo "$Semester"; ?>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <?php echo "$Year"; ?>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <?php echo "$Startsemester"; ?>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <?php echo "$Endsemester"; ?>
                                    </td>
                                    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info">Edit</button>
                                    </td>
                                    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Delete</button>
                                    </td>

                                </tr>


                                <?php
                                //////////
                                }
                                ?>

                            </tbody>
                        </table>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- End PAge Content -->
        </div>
        <!-- End Container fluid  -->





        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <div align="center" class="medium">Back to <a href="index.php?<?php echo htmlspecialchars(SID); ?>">Dashboard</a>
        </div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <!-- All Jquery -->
        <script src="../adminpanel/js/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap tether Core JavaScript -->
        <script src="../adminpanel/js/lib/bootstrap/js/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../adminpanel/js/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- slimscrollbar scrollbar JavaScript -->
        <script src="../adminpanel/js/jquery.slimscroll.js"></script>
        <!--Menu sidebar -->
        <script src="../adminpanel/js/sidebarmenu.js"></script>
        <!--stickey kit -->
        <script src="../adminpanel/js/lib/sticky-kit-master/dist/sticky-kit.min.js"></script>
        <!--Custom JavaScript -->
        <script src="../adminpanel/js/custom.min.js"></script>




        <div id="feedback-modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
                        <h3>Setup Your Course</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form class="feedback" name="feedback">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <label>Department</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="Department" id="Department" class="form-control"/>
                                    <br/>
                                    <label>Course Number</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="CourseNumber" id="CourseNumber" class="form-control"/>
                                    <br/>
                                    <label>Course Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="CourseName" id="CourseName" class="form-control"/>
                                    <br/>

                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">

                                    <label>Section Number</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="SectionNumber" id="SectionNumber" class="form-control"/>
                                    <br/>

                                    <label>Faculty</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="Faculty" id="Faculty" class="form-control"/>
                                    <br/>
                                    <label>Semester</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="Semester" id="Semester" class="form-control"/>
                                    <br/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">

                                    <label>Year</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="Year" id="Year" class="form-control"/>
                                    <br/>
                                    <label>Semester Start</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="Startsemester" id="Startsemester" class="form-control"/>
                                    <br/>
                                    <label>Semester End</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="Endsemester" id="Startsemester" class="form-control"/>
                                    <br/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="operation" id="operation"/>

                        <!--<input type="submit" name="action" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add"/> -->
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" onclick="return false;">Send</button>


                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>



        <script>
            $( "button#submit" ).click( function () {

                $.ajax( {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "insert.php",
                    data: $( 'form.feedback' ).serialize(),

                    success: function ( data ) {
                        alert( data );
                        $( "#feedback" ).html( data );
                        setTimeout( function () {
                            $( "#feedback" ).addClass( 'hide' );
                            $( '.close' ).trigger( 'click' ); // NOTICE THIS CHANGE HERE.
                        }, 5000 );
                    },

                    error: function () {
                        alert( "Error" );
                    }
                } );
                return false;
            } );
        </script>


        <?php
    BodyFooter();
```

Thanks in advance,

Tim

Comment: Shouldn't this be an id not a class? `$(".feedback").addClass('hide');`

Comment: yes @DarrenSweeney, you are right. I have changed that in my answer below and one more change I have done in the same. Waiting for Tim to try that out and tell us how it goes.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney - thank you

Comment: How `#feedback` div will get linked to the modal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way : **NOTE : This is only `success` part of your code.**

can you try by changing the jquery selector from class to ID here:

```
success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
    $("#feedback").html(data);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#feedback").addClass('hide');
        // Added three lines below:
        $('#feedback-modal').modal('hide');
        $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
        $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
    }, 5000);
},
```

This seems very first issue.

Try this out and if it works, I will tell you why it was not working with what you have done.

Comment: thanks for that code! 2 issues with that.  1. The modal doesn't hide and 2. After closing the modal, the entire page is still faded out. Any ideas?

Comment: I posted the modal html at the bottom of my original post

Comment: The success message display but the modal doesn't close. When I close it manually, the page is still faded out.

Comment: I have that line blocked out, but if I enable it, it will show a success message.

Comment: Please update the jquery code which is the final and you are trying with. Because there are so many commented lines and it creates confusions.

Comment: ok @TimM, this final version of the code should fix the issue.

Comment: I updated my original post with all the code I'm currently using. With the new code after I click the close button in the modal, the page is still faded and nothing is clickable.

Comment: Did you change your code with my updated answer? I changed my answer a couple of minutes ago.

Comment: Yes, I just updated in my original post to show the latest code I'm using.

Comment: The div `<div id="feedback">` is on the page, not on modal, Right? And the success messages will be added into it, so that once modal goes away, user can see the message on the page not on modal. Am I getting it right?

Comment: You are correct. I just added my entire html page in my original post for clarification.

Comment: Try out my updated answer again. Sorry for so many iterations.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. That finally did the trick! Question - If I were to remove the alert and have the modal hide upon clicking the submit button and show the message on the main page, how would that look?  I removed the setTimeout function but then no success message showed. I'm happy with how it is now, just asking to try and learn more through example. I truly appreciate your help!!!

Comment: Your welcome, I am happy to help. Well, the settimeout will hide the message from `#feedback` div after 5 sec. And it will close the modal at same time. I wonder how you can see the message once modal goes off. Because it will remove the message too.

Comment: I was wondering if the modal could close and still see the success message on the main page?

Comment: yes, you can do that, remove `$("#feedback").addClass('hide');` from settimeout. And it will work like it.

Comment: This does what I was referring to :)

 success: function(data) {
     $("#feedback").html(data);
  $('#feedback-modal').modal('hide');
        $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
        $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#feedback").addClass('hide');
        // Added three lines below:
    }, 5000);
},

Thanks again for all your help!!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `return false;` at the end of the `button#submit` click callback fucntion.
I think your page is reloading after submit.

```
$("button#submit").click(function() {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "insert.php",
                data: $('form.feedback').serialize(),

                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                    $("#feedback").html(data);
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $("#feedback").addClass('hide');
                        $('#feedback-modal').modal('hide'); // Took this line here rather than calling it out.
                    }, 5000);
                },

                error: function() {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
            return false; 
        });
```

Comment: I added like this: <button class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" onclick="jsfunction();return false;">Send</button>    although it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: you do not have a function named jsfunction() right, then how would it have any difference on your code.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to add that and I apparently misunderstood how to add a return false.  I changed it to:  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" onclick="return false;">Send</button>   Is that correct?